# Defining an order to a set of associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design, rails-activerecord

I have two models, Task and Unit. A task has_many :units. I would like to order the units based on some kind of precedence. For example: There are two units A and B. A must be completed before B. Users can add another unit, for example C, between A and B. Unit C could also then be deleted - A and B's precedence will remain intact. Whats the most simple/straight forward way to implement this in Rails?

Ideas I have considered:

1. Adding a precedence integer column to the units table that gets updated on any operations that change the collection of units.
2. Adding a self join association to unit model pointing to the next/previous unit and modifying the associations when the unit collection is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to model your problem depends on how complicated your Task structures are going to be.

If a Task's Units can always be put into first-to-last order, giving each Unit an integer order will make it easiest to put Units into that order, with `order` in ActiveRecord or `sort` in memory. The only disadvantage is that when you add or remove a Unit you may need to save other Units to update their orders. That's probably not a big disadvantage if Tasks have smallish integer numbers of Units.

If a Task can have cycles, each Unit will need a reference to the Unit that precedes it. You might even end up needing a model to represent the relationship between a Unit and the Unit that follows it. So think through the use cases you expect to need to support and see which applies.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I like the idea of using ActiveRecord with order and on handling cyclic tasks. Since I don't have to deal with cyclic tasks I will go with using the integer column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem.
This migration can solve your problem:

```
class AddCachedVotesToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_total, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_score, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_up, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_down, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_score, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_total, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_average, :float, :default => 0.0
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_total
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_score
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_up
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_down
    add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_score
    add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_total
    add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_average

    # Uncomment this line to force caching of existing votes
    # Post.find_each(&:update_cached_votes)
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_total
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_score
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_up
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_down
    remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_score
    remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_total
    remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_average
  end
end
```

Especially this column `add_column :posts, :cached_votes_up, :integer, :default => 0` and this index  `add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_score`